# Mime type missing description?

Tags: software-installation, mime-type, file-association

I am trying to create file associations so I can double click a file and it will open with my program - and will associate an icon with that file type.

I created the file `myapp-xxx.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="application/myapp-xxx">
        <comment>My app dummy mime</comment>
        <sub-class-of type="application/octet-stream"/>
        <glob pattern="*.xxx"/>
        <generic-icon name="MyApp"/>
    </mime-type>    
</mime-info>
```

I placed `MyApp.png` in `/usr/share/icons/`

I placed `myapp-xxx.xml` in `/usr/share/mime/application/`

I ran

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

and my xml promptly disappeared.

I read that it can be because i am missing description... but looking at all the examples, and the existing mimes, I don't see what I am missing.

12.04

Note: I have a .desktop file too... but since the mime database removes the mime, I don't think having the reference in the .desktop file will help.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! .xxx is not a valid mime type you will likely have better luck using a valid type. A rather exhaustive list can be found here: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

Comment: You may find this Q&A on superuser.com to be helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/649928/how-does-linux-decide-on-a-default-application

Comment: I made xxx up - trying to make a custom mime type - using the file extension of the files saved . If I use an existing mime type, I may as well just use application/octet-stream right ? Just read the link  above - so i must place my mime description in the packages not application - and have to name it after my application, without the little extra I added ? what if an application installs multiple mime types ?

Comment: Hopefully the Q&A on superuser.com will more helpful in allowing you to achieve your intendeed result.

Comment: I moved the xml file in packages and it didn't get deleted anymore. Running mimetype -a myfile.xxx showed both mime types.

Comment: Excellent. Feel free to write your own answer (that's encouraged here). It may help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the file `myapp-xxx.xml` in `/usr/share/mime/packages/` (instead of `/usr/share/mime/application/`)

Running  `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` did not remove my xml file...

Running `mimetype -a Desktop/abcd.xxx` showed

```
Desktop/abcd.xxx: application/myapp-xxx
Desktop/abcd.xxx: application/octet-stream
```

Thank you Elder Geek for the resource.